# How to classify elements in a linear array under constraints?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, mathematical-optimization, greedy

I face a problem that is more logical in nature, but at the end I have to design an algorithm to solve it, so that's why I post it here. Perhaps someone will provide a fresh perspective on the problem, which can be helpful too.

Imagine you have the list of all dates in 2022 in their natural order. Those dates need to be assigned to 3 different categories: `A`, `B` and `C`. (The last one is just a fallback category to make things simpler.) All the dates from category `A` are already given. For concreteness let's say that they come in two blocks: 1 April 2022 till (and inclusive) 10 April 2022 and 1 July 2022 till (and inclusive) 7 July 2022. Now the challenge is to assign as many days to category `B` as possible under the following rules:
Rule 1: Each date has to be assigned to exactly one category.
Rule 2: Category `A` stays the way it is. No dates are allowed to be changed, removed or added.
Rule 3: There can be no more than 14 consecutive dates assigned to category `B`.
Rule 4: Between any two non-consecutive dates that belong to category `B` there must be at least 30 days that are either in category `A` or `C`.

I think that there are potentially multiple solutions (i.e., configurations of dates classified as `B`) that maximize the number of days in category `B` over the entire 2022.
What would be a good strategy to arrive at a classification with as many days in category `B` as possible?

I am thinking of using something like a greedy algorithm: starting from the beginning of the year, grabbing as many days as possible (in this case 14), assigning them to `B`. Then counting 30 days, checking which of those 30 days are in `A` and assigning the other ones to `C`. After this step I will have essentially a smaller version of the same problem as before, i.e., it's a recursive solution that is applied until all dates are categorized. However, I am not sure if that's a good way to approach the problem. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious. In addition, the blocks in category `A` could vary in size, position and number.

Comment: The problem with greedy is what happens if you can get 5 days now, or 7 days after some block of A. Which you want to do will depend on what happens later in the year.

Comment: Seems like a dynamic programming approach could work.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to decide, for some day number `d` (starting at 0 for January 1), whether to assign A, B, or C. What do you need to know?

- If it's in one of the predefined A chunks, you have to assign it A.
- Otherwise, you need to know something about the days leading up to day `d`. Call this info the “prior”.

  - If the prior is at least 1 but less than 30 non-B-days, you must assign C. Let's refer to non-B-days as X-days for brevity.
  - If the prior is 14 B-days, you must assign C.
- Otherwise, you can assign either B or C, in which case you want to consider both:

  - If you assign B for day `d`, what's the best B-count you can get for the remainder of the year (including the B you're assigning)?
  - If you assign C for day `d`, what's the best B-count you can get for the remainder of the year?

  Pick the B or C assignment that gives the best B-count for the remainder of the year.

Notice that this decision process is recursive: to make the optimal decision for `d`, we generally need to have computed the optimal assignments for the remainder of the year under multiple priors. A naive implementation would therefore be exponential in time.

But there are only a fixed number of priors possible for any day of the year: the prior can be one of 1 to 14 B-days, or it can be 1 to 30 X-days. Technically it can be more than 30 X-days, but we can stop counting them at 30 because 31 X-days has the same effect as 30 X-days.

So let's cache the best assignments in a dictionary. Each key is a day number and a prior together, and the corresponding value is the best assignment possible for the remainder of the year starting at that day with that prior.

This strategy is called [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

I'm going to use Swift to spell out the algorithm precisely. I hope you can read it.

Here's how I'll represent the prior. In case you're not familiar, Swift's `enum` is more powerful than C/C++/Java `enum`s. It is technically called a “sum type” or a “discriminated union”, and it can have extra data associated with each case:

```swift
enum Prior: Hashable {
    // Preceded by this many consecutive B-days.
    case bDays(Int)

    // Preceded by this many consecutive non-B-days.
    case xDays(Int)
}
```

Here's how I'll represent day codes:

```swift
enum DayCode: Character, CustomStringConvertible {
    case a = "a"
    case b = "b"
    case c = "c"

    var description: String { "\(rawValue)" }
}
```

I'll model an assignment as an array of day codes, which are the codes for some tail part of the year ending at December 31, along with the number of B days in the assignment. I have a couple of helper methods that can prepend one or more days onto the assignment:

```swift
struct Assignment {
    var codes: [DayCode]
    var bCount: Int

    func prepending(_ code: DayCode, repeated n: Int) -> Self {
        return .init(
            codes: Array(repeating: code, count: n) + codes,
            bCount: bCount + (code == .b ? n : 0)
        )
    }

    func prepending(_ code: DayCode) -> Self {
        return .init(
            codes: [code] + codes,
            bCount: bCount + (code == .b ? 1 : 0)
        )
    }
}
```

For the cache dictionary, I'll need a key type that combines the day number and the prior:

```swift
struct Key: Hashable {
    // Days are counted from zero. 0 = January 1.
    var day: Int
    var prior: Prior
}
```

I also need the constants from your spec:

```swift
// Not a leap year, so day 366 is the first day of next year.
let endDay = 365

// Maximum number of consecutive B days allowed.
let bMax = 14

// Minimum number of non-B-days required between B day chunks.
let xMin = 30

// Key = first day number of chunk. Value = number of days in chunk.
let aChunks: [Int: Int] = [
    // April 1
    31 + 28 + 31: 10,

    // July 1
    31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30: 7,
]
```

Here's the cache, stored in a Swift dictionary, along with a function that looks in the cache before calling the real computation:

```swift
var _bestAssignments: [Key: Assignment] = [:]

func bestAssignment(for key: Key) -> Assignment {
    if let existing = _bestAssignments[key] {
        return existing
    }

    let best = computeBestAssignment(for: key)
    _bestAssignments[key] = best

    return best
}
```

Finally, here's the real computation, which examines each of the possible cases I described above:

```swift
func computeBestAssignment(for key: Key) -> Assignment {
    guard key.day < endDay else {
        return .init(codes: [], bCount: 0)
    }

    if let aCount =  aChunks[key.day] {
        let bestAfter: Assignment
        switch key.prior {
        case .bDays(_):
            bestAfter = bestAssignment(for: .init(
                day: key.day + aCount,
                prior: .xDays(aCount)
            ))
        case .xDays(let xCount):
            bestAfter = bestAssignment(for: .init(
                day: key.day + aCount,
                prior: .xDays(xCount + aCount)
            ))
        }
        return bestAfter.prepending(.a, repeated: aCount)
    }

    switch key.prior {
    case .bDays(let bCount):
        guard bCount < bMax else {
            // Max B-days already reached, so today has to be a C-day.
            return bestAssignment(for: .init(
                day: key.day + 1,
                prior: .xDays(1)
            )).prepending(.c)
        }

        // I can add a B-day or a C-day. Do
        // whichever gets me the best count for the
        // remainder of the year including today.

        let bAdded = bestAssignment(for: .init(
            day: key.day + 1,
            prior: .bDays(bCount + 1)
        )).prepending(.b)
        let cAdded = bestAssignment(for: .init(
            day: key.day + 1,
            prior: .xDays(1)
        )).prepending(.c)
        return bAdded.bCount > cAdded.bCount ? bAdded : cAdded

    case .xDays(let xCount):
        guard xCount >= xMin else {
            // Not enough non-B-days yet, so today has to be a C-day.
            return bestAssignment(for: .init(
                day: key.day + 1,
                prior: .xDays(xCount + 1)
            )).prepending(.c)
        }

        // I can add a B-day or a C-day. Do
        // whichever gets me the best count for the
        // remainder of the year including today.

        let bAdded = bestAssignment(for: .init(
            day: key.day + 1,
            prior: .bDays(1)
        )).prepending(.b)

        // As an optimization, I clamp xDays to xMin,
        // because for choosing assignments, all
        // larger xDays have the same effect as xMin.
        let cAdded = bestAssignment(for: .init(day: key.day + 1, prior: .xDays(
            min(xMin, xCount + 1)
        ))).prepending(.c)

        return bAdded.bCount > cAdded.bCount ? bAdded : cAdded
    }
}
```

For printing out the best assignment succinctly, I'll use this function to run-length-encode the day code array:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func runLengthEncoded() -> [(Element, Int)] {
        guard let first else { return [] }
        var answer: [(Element, Int)] = [(first, 1)]
        for element in dropFirst() {
            if element == answer[answer.count - 1].0 {
                answer[answer.count - 1].1 += 1
            } else {
                answer.append((element, 1))
            }
        }
        return answer
    }
}
```

Finally, I can compute and print the best assignment:

```swift
let assignment = bestAssignment(for: .init(day: 0, prior: .xDays(xMin)))
print(assignment.bCount, assignment.codes.runLengthEncoded())
```

Running on my MacBook Pro, unoptimized, gives this output:

```
; time testapp                               
114 [(b, 2), (c, 30), (b, 14), (c, 30), (b, 14), (a, 10), (c, 23), (b, 14), (c, 30), (b, 14), (a, 7), (c, 31), (b, 14), (c, 30), (b, 14), (c, 30), (b, 14), (c, 30), (b, 14)]
testapp  0.03s user 0.01s system 88% cpu 0.040 total
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the quick and elaborate answer! I didn't expect to get a reply that fast. Casting the problem as a dynamic-programming type of problem makes sense. However, I am still trying to understand how the symmetry of this problem fits into the category of dynamic-programming problems. In those type of problems one boundary is set and from there we calculate the rest based on some rules. But in my problem both ends are equally undefined. I can flip the days, i.e. 1 Jan becomes 31 Dec and so on. Applying the maximization code from different ends should give the same number of B days.

Comment: By the way, there seems to be a small bug in your code, since it has produced 15 consecutive B days.
I am also surprised that it didn't decide to start with 14 B days right from the beginning, since this is what my "greedy" code would have done, and I would also expect that due to intuition. On the other hand, it ends with a sequence of 14 B days and going back to the symmetry of the problem, that might be just as good.

Comment: The bug was that the comparison `bCount <= bMax` should have been `bCount < bMax`. I have fixed my answer and changed the output format so that it is easier to spot this bug (or its absence).